# Is array as an argument in c really reference type?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fun(int *arr)
{
    arr=(int *)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    arr[0]=5;
    arr[1]=4;
    printf("in fun {%d, %d}",arr[0],arr[1]);
}

void anotherFunction(int *arr) 
{
    arr[0]=4;
    arr[1]=5;
    printf("in fun {%d, %d}",arr[0],arr[1]);
}

int main(void) 
{
    int *arr,*emptyInMain;
    int arr2[]={99,99};
    arr=(int *)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    arr[0]=99;
    arr[1]=99;

    printf("arr ");
    fun(arr);
    printf("\narr in main {%d, %d}\n",arr[0],arr[1]);

    printf("emptyInMain");
    fun(emptyInMain);
    //printf("\narr in main {%d, %d}\n",emptyInMain[0],emptyInMain[1]);    // WILL GIVE RUNTIME ERROR
    printf("\n\--commented the line in the code because emptyInMain[0],emptyInMain[1] will give RUNTIME ERROR--");

    printf("\narr2");
    fun(arr2);
    printf("\narr2 in main {%d, %d}\n",arr2[0],arr2[1]);

    printf("\nfollowing output shows expected behaviour\n");

    printf("\narr2");
    anotherFunction(arr2);
    printf("\narr2 in main {%d, %d}\n",arr2[0],arr2[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

We all know that passing array as argument is a call by reference. As if I send an array arr={99,99} to a function which makes arr[0]=4 and arr[1]=5, the values get changed to 4 and 5 in the calling function also. The same should be applicable if I send the address of the variable and some manipulation is done in other function.

The following output of the above code confused me. I want to be assured if what I am thinking is correct or not.

```
arr in fun {5, 4}
arr in main {99, 99}
emptyInMainin fun {5, 4}
--commented the line in the code because emptyInMain[0],emptyInMain[1] will give RUNTIME ERROR--
arr2in fun {5, 4}
arr2 in main {99, 99}

following output shows expected behaviour

arr2in fun {4, 5}
arr2 in main {4, 5}
```

Only the last output shows the change.

Why I think arr did not get changed in first three cases is we are sending address of arr which is stored in local variable of fun(). This local variable starts pointing to some other address after the statement:

```
arr=(int *)malloc(2*sizeof(int));
```

anotherFunction() is the only function that doesn't change the allocation of its own local variable and manipulates the value stored in its (local variable's) address.

Please let me know if following assumptions of mine are wrong. Also please let me know what best change can I make to make values in the array change in all the cases. What could I do to make the variable point to location by means of malloc inside the called function (I guess double pointer but not sure).

Comment: remember a key point is, C passes all parameters by VALUE, even a reference.

Comment: @scarecrow-, yes, but another key point to remember is that C does not have references.

Comment: If you want the function change its argument's value, you should pass argument's address as argument in the call, and dereference the _pointer_ inside the function.

Comment: Arrays are never passed **at all**.  If an expression appearing as a function argument nominally has an array type then the value of the expression *decays* to a pointer (as also happens in almost all other contexts).  The resulting pointer is passed, by value.  The argument is a pointer, not an array.

Comment: @scarecrow- that's really an amazing truth.

Comment: What @JohnBollinger said. Furthermore, if a function *parameter* looks like an array, its type is *adjusted* to pointer. Which may cause some confusion.

Comment: @JohnBollinger How does the call by reference actually be like? Because java and C# also send object to other function. Isn't address of those object being sent in that case. Isn't address of object being passed as a value in that case?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: @gj1103, Java is also strictly pass-by-value, as I think C# also is.  In Java, at least, you can never actually touch an object at all -- you handle only primitives and references, but references are passed *by value*.  You can confirm this by assigning a new value to a method argument -- the reference in the caller does not change.  C++, on the other hand, has both pass-by-value and pass-by-reference.  Fortran has *only* pass by reference.

Comment: @John Bollinger Hmmm, from the __caller's point-of-view__: `char s[5]; strcpy(s, "abc");`, the result is that array `s[]` is updated as one would expect if one said `s` was passed by reference.  Of course the underlying C  mechanism of the function call (converting the formal parameter `s` to the actual argument `&s[0]`) prior to function invocation and the function receiving the value as type `char *` is indeed pass-by-value.

Comment: @chux, inasmuch as the caller can determine by examination that evaluating the argument expression yields a *pointer*, not an array, there can be no question of an array being passed at all.  That the observed effect of evaluating the function call is equivalent to the effect that would be expected if the array involved were passed to the function by reference does not mean that it indeed was passed, whether by reference or otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question in your title, C parameters are always passed by value, never by reference. What makes arrays different is that when you pass an array as a parameter, it's automatically converted to a pointer to the first element of the array, and this is the value that's passed. All other types of parameters are passed by making a copy of the value.

In either case, assigning to the parameter variable in the function has no effect on the caller's variable. When the parameter is a pointer, you can indirect through it to access the caller's data. And if it's a pointer to an array element, you can index it to access the caller's array. That's what happens in your `anotherfunction()` function.

If you want to allocate the array in the function and have this affect the caller, there are two ways to do it.

First is to have the function return the pointer:

```
int *fun() {
    int *localarr = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    localarr[0] = 4;
    localarr[1] = 5;
    return localarr;
}
```

Then the caller would do:

```
arr = fun();
```

The second way is to pass a pointer to a pointer.

```
void fun(int **arrparam) {
    int *localarr = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    localarr[0] = 4;
    localarr[1] = 5;
    *arrparam = localarr;
}
```

Then the caller does:

```
fun(&arr);
```

Comment: Not to take from this fine answer explaining 2 ways (maybe others exsit?) to accomplish OPs higher goal, it does not answer the title question "Is array as an argument in c really reference type?" - which is 1/2 step from a holy-war question.  Suggest OP rename question to match the goal: something along the line of how to pass array info back to a caller.

Comment: @chux I chose to answer the question in the text, not the question in the title.

Comment: Yes - that is clear, but it is the title that leads folks to this post and it would be better if the title matched OP's question intent and the selected answer.

Comment: I've added an answer to the title as well.

Comment: @Barmar could you please help me by answering the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37764258/why-character-pointer-is-getting-assigned-just-a-character-while-a-string-is-su?noredirect=1#comment62997129_37764258

Answer (score 1):

> What could I do to make the variable point to location by means of malloc inside the called function so that variable in main also starts pointing to the new location (I guess double pointer but not sure).

In order to do that, you have pass a pointer to a pointer (that's your double pointer).

```
foo(int** ptr)
{
   *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
   (*ptr)[0] = 10;
   (*ptr)[1] = 20;
}

int main()
{
   int* ptr;
   foo(&ptr);  // Use the & operator to pass a pointer to the pointer.

   // Check to make sure that the values are as expected.
   assert(ptr[0] == 10);
   assert(ptr[1] == 20);

   // deallocate the memory
   free(ptr);
}
```