# Why character pointer is getting assigned just a character, while a string is supposed to get assigned to it?

Tags: c, string, pointers, split

A string contains three parts separated by space. First two parts are strings and the third part is an integer.

The output of the below program is surprising me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void split(char *ch,char **part1,char **part2,int *num){
    int length=strlen(ch), *lc1,*lc2;
    int i=0,j=0;
    printf("value of length is %d\n",length);

    printf("this function recieved %s for splitting into pieces\n",ch);

    lc1=(char *)malloc(length*sizeof(char));
    lc2=(char *)malloc(length*sizeof(char));

    while(ch[i]!=' '){
        lc1[i]=ch[i];
        printf("\nin loop with lc1[i] = %c and ch[i] =  %c",lc1[i],ch[i]);
        i++;
    }
    lc1[i]='\0';
    i++;
    while(ch[i]!=' '){
        lc2[j]=ch[i];
        printf("\nin loop with lc2[j] = %c and ch[i] =  %c",lc2[j],ch[i]);
        j++;
        i++;
    }
    lc2[j]='\0';
    i++;
    *num=atoi(&ch[i]);

    *part1=lc1;
    *part2=lc2;

    printf("\nsplit results are:\n");
    printf("part1=%s and part2=%s and num=%d and lc1=%s lc2=%s    //this is surprising me",*part1,*part2,*num,lc1,lc2);

}

int main()
{
    int N,i,j,n,*numArray,count=0;
    char **arr,*part1,*part2,*token;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    arr=malloc(N*sizeof **arr);
    numArray=malloc(N*sizeof *numArray);
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    arr[i]=(char *)malloc(50*sizeof(char));
    }

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        printf("plz enter %d th :",i);
        scanf(" ");
        gets(&arr[i][0]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        printf("%s",arr[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    /*token=strtok(arr[i]," ");
    part1=token;
    token=strtok(NULL," ");
    part2=token;
    token=strtok(NULL," ");
    n=atoi(token);*/
        split(arr[i],&part1,&part2,&n);
    //some logic to use part1 and part2 of the sentence
}
return 0;

}
```

Input I provided is as below:

```
1
abcd efgh 2
```

The first line of the input contains number of sentences I want to proceed.
Output I got is as below:

```
plz enter 0 th :abcd efgh 2value of length is 11
this function recieved abcd efgh 2 for splitting into pieces

in loop with lc1[i] = a and ch[i] =  a
in loop with lc1[i] = b and ch[i] =  b
in loop with lc1[i] = c and ch[i] =  c
in loop with lc1[i] = d and ch[i] =  d
in loop with lc2[j] = e and ch[i] =  e
in loop with lc2[j] = f and ch[i] =  f
in loop with lc2[j] = g and ch[i] =  g
in loop with lc2[j] = h and ch[i] =  h
split results are:
part1=a and part2=e and num=2 and lc1=a lc2=e    //this is surprising me
Success time: 0 memory: 2296 signal:0
plz enter 0 th :abcd efgh 2value of length is 11
this function recieved abcd efgh 2 for splitting into pieces

in loop with lc1[i] = a and ch[i] =  a
in loop with lc1[i] = b and ch[i] =  b
in loop with lc1[i] = c and ch[i] =  c
in loop with lc1[i] = d and ch[i] =  d
in loop with lc2[j] = e and ch[i] =  e
in loop with lc2[j] = f and ch[i] =  f
in loop with lc2[j] = g and ch[i] =  g
in loop with lc2[j] = h and ch[i] =  h
split results are:
part1=a and part2=e and num=2 and lc1=a lc2=e    //this is surprising me
```

Although the loop function inside the split() is getting executed successfully for all the characters in the string, yet I am getting just a character in part1 (also in lc1) and part2 (also in lc2). What is the reason for this output?

Comment: Don't cast `malloc()`. `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition. Don't use `gets`. Don't use `scanf` for user input.

Comment: `arr=malloc(N*sizeof **arr);` -->> `arr=malloc(N*sizeof *arr);` (also *style*: try to add some whitespace, and replace the while() loops by for() loops where you can)

Comment: You have some type errors around `lc1`/`lc2`. Doesn't your compiler warn you about those? (Specifically, they're declared as `int *` but initialized/used as if they were `char *`.)

Comment: @melpomene could you please suggest something else in place of scanf to take user's input?

Comment: `fgets()` would be a good one @ gj1103

Comment: @melpomene thanks a lot man! that char * was the cause of unexpected output? But I don't know what internally happened and why ws there no error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
arr=malloc(N*sizeof **arr);
```

it should be:

```
arr=malloc(N*sizeof *arr);
```

`**arr` is a `char`, so it's only allocating space for `N` bytes, but you need space for `N` pointers, which are 4 bytes. So you're not allocating enough space, and then you're writing outside the array bounds, resulting in undefined behavior.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/cwcvrN)

Comment: the error was due to *lc1,*lc2; being declared as int... but i am unable to figure out why exactly was happening with *lc1 and *lc2 being declared, and why it didn't give error...

Comment: They were declared as `char *` when I answered the question. You edited the question after I posted my answer.

Comment: there's a long story... initially it was int...then i thought it was a typo... so i made it char... then i realized code behaved unexpectedly just because of that only... so i reverted the change in the question... melpomene (in comments) helped me out in understanding the mistake... @Barmar Sorry for that...